# PowerShell Verify password change was successful by creating and using credential object

Tags: powershell

PowerShell 5.1

I would like to test credentials after changing password for an array of computers for a `User1`.

```
function SetUser1Paswword($hosts, $credential, $newPassword) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hosts -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
        $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $using:newPassword -AsPlainText -Force
        Set-LocalUser -Name User1 -Password $securePassword -Verbose
    }
}
```

Is there an easy one-liner I can use to test new password on each machine, with something like an `Invoke-Command` or something easy to test.

Comment: Are the hosts domain joined? Also, whats the point on validating? If the cmdlet didnt throw an error then its already ensured the password was updated

Comment: Yeah, you're right. They are domain joined. The user is a local user, which doesn't work with Kerberos apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially if `Set-LocalUser` did not throw, it's already ensured the new password was successfully set. You can implement a `Try Catch` for handling possible errors in case its needed.

```
function SetUser1Paswword($hosts, $credential, $newPassword) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hosts -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
        $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $using:newPassword -AsPlainText -Force
        try {
            Set-LocalUser -Name User1 -Password $securePassword -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch {
            # handling here
        }
    }
}
```

As for validating a password, assuming this are local accounts the following might work using using [`PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.validatecredentials?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0):

```
function SetUser1Paswword($hosts, $credential, $newPassword) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hosts -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
        $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $using:newPassword -AsPlainText -Force
        try {
            Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
            Set-LocalUser -Name User1 -Password $securePassword -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
            $context = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new(
                [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine)
            $context.ValidateCredentials('User1', $using:newPassword) # Should be True
        }
        catch {
            # handling here
        }
    }
}
```